# Integral convergence question

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Let $ f: [a,\infty ) \to \mathbb R $ be $ f\in C([a,\infty)) $, with a cycle $ T > 0 $,

and let $ g: [a,\infty ) \to \mathbb R $ be a monotonic function, and $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$$

Assume that $$ \int_a^{a+T} f(x)\,dx = 0 $$

Prove that: $$ \int_a^\infty f(x)g(x)\,dx $$
converges.

Help?

Comment: In the intergral of $f$, the upper limit is $T$, not $t$, I presume?

Comment: oh.. right... I'll fix... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are sequences such that

$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = 0 \\
$$
and there exists a $M$ such that for all $N$
$$
 | \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{n} | \leq M,
$$
i.e. the partial sum is bounded, then
$$
 \sum a_{n} b_{n}
$$
converges.

Comment: I imagine that you are referring to Dirichlet's test, but how do you show that $\int_a^x f(x) $ is blocked?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by blocked? Do you have an idea what you would choose for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$?

Comment: I'm sorry for my English, but by "blocked" I mean that there is an $ M > 0 $ that for every $x$ , $f(x) < M$

Comment: A yes, well I don't know how you want to use this, but since $f$ is periodic, $\sup_{x \in [a,\infty)} | f(x) | = \sup_{x \in [a,a+T]} | f(x) |$. This is the supremum of a continuous function on a compact set and is therefore attained, i.e. there exists a $\xi \in [a,a+T]$ such that $| f(x) | \leq | f(\xi) |$ for all $x$. Therefore $f$ is bounded (that is the known term) by $f(\xi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that $g(x)\ge 0$.

First, let $a=\int_0^T \lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx$, then 
\begin{align}
\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx&=\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,\big(g(x)-g(s+T)\big)\,dx+\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,g(s+T)\,dx \\
&=\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,\big(g(x)-g(s+T)\big)\,dx+g(s+T)\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,dx
\\
&=\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,\big(g(x)-g(s+T)\big)\,dx,
\end{align}
and hence
$$
\Big|\int_s^{s+T}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\,\Big|\le \big(g(s)-g(s+T)\big)\int_s^{s+T}\lvert f(x)\rvert\,\,dx=a\big(g(s)-g(s+T)\big).
$$

We need to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $M>0$, such that, for every $N>M$,
$$
\Big|\int_M^N f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\,\Big|<\varepsilon.
$$
As $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$, let $M>0$, such that $$ag(M)<\varepsilon.$$ Let now $N>M$, and assume that
$$
M<M+s<\cdots<M+ks\le N<M+(k+1)s.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_M^N f(x)\,g(x)\,dx&=\sum_{j=1}^k \int_{M+(j-1)s}^{M+js}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx+\int_{M+ks}^{N}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k \int_{M+(j-1)s}^{M+js}f(x)\,\big(g(x)-g(M+js)\big)\,dx+\int_{M+ks}^{N}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx,
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
\Big|\int_M^N f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\,\Big|&\le 
\sum_{j=1}^k \int_{M+(j-1)s}^{M+js} \lvert f(x)\rvert\,\big(g(x)-g(M+js)\big)\,dx+\int_{M+ks}^{N}\lvert f(x)\rvert\,g(x)\,dx \\ &\le 
\sum_{j=1}^k a\big(g(M+(j-1)s)-g(M+js)\big)+ag(M+ks)=ag(M)<\varepsilon.
\end{align}